# How to specify onActivityResult() for 2 views?

Tags: android

I have 3 views in my application.
My first view (FIRST_VIEW) has 2 buttons (BTN_2 and BTN_3).
Each button will start seperate views, means BTN_2 causes to start SECOND_VIEW and BTN_3 will start THIRD_VIEW. In my FIRST_VIEW i have one onActivityResult() function. How can I set two onActivityResult() functions for each button result (that is from SECOND_VIEW and from THIRD_VIEW)? How can I specify that onActivityResult() function for each view?
Please Help me.....
Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one onActivityResult. You need to to check the resultCode and requestCode for actually identifying the activity.

```
startActivityForResult(intentSecond, 1002);
startActivityForResult(intentThird, 1003);
@override
void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if(requestCode==1002) //it was Second Activity
  else if(requestCode==1003) //it was Third Activity
}
```